# Cross Compile ffmpeg for Zedboard?

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compiling

This is the first time I heard of cross compilation; and I tried extensively to read about it and what would be the procedure for doing the above mentioned activity.

I want to use ffmpeg onto an Xilinx zedboard which has debian in it.

Could anyone highlight the basic steps as to what do I have to do for cross compilation? (I'm using a linux machine with ubuntu OS 16.04)

NOTE: For reference I have the following questions:

```
1) Do I need to install Xilinx tools? (ex. Vivado)
2) Is arm.xilinx.linux.gnueabi.gcc required? If yes, How do I install     
   that?
3) Do I have to compile directly into the zedboard or in my machine with 
   ubuntu first? 
4) What is this OpenCV and what is it's relationship with ffmpeg? Do I 
   need OpenCV?
```

Thanks in advance